# How to count Based on Dynamic Range in excel?

Tags: excel, range

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN0tS.png)

I want to loop through Coloum to bring the value as the following Example:

in Cell **E4**

If A4 >= **C4** && A4 <= **D4**, Bring the value of B4

If A5 >= **C4** && A5 <= **D4**, Bring the value of B5

If A6 >= **C4** && A6 <= **D4**, Bring the value of B6

Up to

If A27 >= **C4** && A27 <= **D4**, Bring the value of B27

then I will sum all the brought values.

Then to continue in Cell **E5** with the same criteria up to cell E27

Comment: ^^Please supply some test data and expected outcome. I also am not clear what happens when going to cell E5. Hasn't E4 already dealt with A4:A27?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few days to do this but the easiest is probably with `SUMIFS`.

For example, this:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,"<="&A:A,D:D,">="&A:A)
```

...will give you the sum of cells in `Column B` where `Column A` is between `Column C` and `Column D`.

(This tested fine on a couple rows that I tried but that's all I was willing to test since (as was mentioned) an image of your data isn't very helpful.)

You can adjust it to contain whichever area needs to be included/excluded and you can use add the results of multiple `SUMIFS` functions to sum results from different areas.

---

### More Information

- Office.com : [**`SUMIFS` Function**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) (with Video)

Comment: I don't get what you mean but the question isn't absolutely clear either.  I don't believe a loop is necessary if column is singular.  OP mentions `Column E` (which isn't included in the sample) but if this column adds correctly, the other should be no issue